# no response from modules from nodeschool.io

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm a total newbie to node.

The issue is that after I install a module from nodeschool.io and type the name of the module on the command line, nothing happens and it just returns to command prompt.

I'm using an EC2 instance from AWS in which I ssh from my macbook.
I have apt-get install node.js and installed one of the learning modules from nodeschool.io -- I started with `learnyoumode`.

From the instructions, it said to simply type `learnyounode` and you should see a screen which I don't.
It just comes back to the command line.

I have verified it is not an 'X' issue with AWS because when I type 'xclock', the clock does launch.

I think this is an issue with AWS and not the module -- my assumption, TIA

usaims

Comment: From a macbook simply install node.js from nodejs.org than in the terminal `sudo npm install learnyounode -g`, then just `learyounode` in the terminal. Note their are ways to avoid the sudo.  If that doesn't work you can use http://generalhenry.com/learnyounode (ping me if that link doesn't work)

Comment: Thanks generalhenry that worked and I'm ok with learning nodejs on my mac. I kind of wanted to learn nodejs on my AWS instance since it has a static IP and apache installed on it. Thanks again.